# Database Encryption for SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, encryption

We are looking for an data encryption for our SQL Server database, we have maintain our customer details in some tables and more tables are related each other’s. We are in the confusion of doing encryption at column level or database level. We have more queries in our application which process in the SQL Server database.

Also we are doing database replication process which will replicate our production database to another database in our secondary server. We will use the replicated secondary server for reporting purpose. I have there queries.

Regarding this:

1. What will the better encryption database level or column level? I can find some articles which prefer column level and which says only encrypt sensitive required columns, instead of whole database.
2. Is "Always Encrypted" feature or TDE which one to choice? Both have problems with performance, and always encrypted is better than TDE based on some analysis. I couldn't come to any conclusion on this. Which one we can go with, or else any other option other than this? Also I can find some commercial products which take care of this encryption, can we choice any better products?
3. Some products mentioned no query changes required if we use their product for database encryption, we have lot of join, complex queries which involved using customer information, those columns needs to be encrypted. If we encrypt those columns, it's possible to achieve without any query level changes in our applications?
4. Why doesn't always encrypted support database replication? I found some articles which says always encrypted not supported replication. If it's not supported replication, what is the alternate way to do the replication for encrypted columns? We are depended on database replication for our reporting purpose.

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: For data at rest encryption, the simplest solution is whole-disk encryption.

Comment: what you mean rest encryption, we are using active database, our site will query the database all time.

Comment: "At rest" means that you're only concerned with protecting the data from people who can examine the database while it's not in use -- that is, people who have access to backup files, volume snapshots and even old drives. If you are additionally concerned with protecting the data from database administrators, that's where Always Encrypted comes in -- here the plaintext is not available on the server, even to the database engine, and only clients with the key can decrypt it. To effectively protect data, you must first identify who and what you're protecting against.